# convert array_agg output to array and not string

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using `array_agg` to group values into an array. The output for row is:

```
row: anonymous { values: '{(1),(2)}' }
```

I'm trying to then loop through the results in Node,

`row.values.forEach(...` but it says `values.forEach` is not a function, because `typeof row.values` is String.

I'm using array_agg, so why is the output a string, and how can I convert it to an array?

Comment: The Postgres wire protocol represents pretty much everything as a printable string; it's up to the client driver to convert it into a native data type (int, float, boolean, etc). Arrays are relatively rare, so most drivers don't have built-in handling for them. Unfortunately, the string format is rather hard to parse; one workaround is to use `array_to_json` to get something more readily parseable. (Not answering, because I don't know specifically about this driver.)

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this problem too and unnest wasn't an option due to needing a fixed number of rows to be returned and I couldn't guarantee my content wouldn't contain a `,` or brackets which made a regex solution challenging.

I found the best solution was to use `json_agg` instead of `array_agg`. (See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)) This returned the results in JSON format and node automatically interpreted it as a javascript object so you can use `.forEach` without any conversion needed.

Answer (score 1):

Can convert an array to a set of rows by using: [**unnest**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html)

```
create temp table t (name text);
insert into t values ('name1'),('name2'),('name3'),('name4');

select unnest(array_agg(name)) as aname from t

+-------+
| aname |
+-------+
| name1 |
+-------+
| name2 |
+-------+
| name3 |
+-------+
| name4 |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting integers in the array, you can use regex and loop through the matches of `(\d+)`.

Another method is to use `array_to_string` and have it join using values that do not appear in the content, a newline `\n` for example: `array_to_string(some_array_content, E'\n')`, then split it later.

Once you get it into an array one way or another, `forEach` will work.

Also, I believe Sequelize can handle arrays: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/datatypes/#array

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about `knex`, but for [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg), you can cast the results of `array_agg` to an array type, i.e. `::int[]` and it will return an array instead of a string:

```
SELECT 
  array_agg(name)::int[],
  foo_id
FROM bar 
GROUP BY foo_id;
```